# While read line in linux not read iterations

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I try to parse **journald**

generate some errors manually:

```
for i in {1..10}; do 
echo "some error #$i " | systemd-cat -p err;
done
```

and i can see it by **journalctl**:

```
journalctl -f -n 0 | grep -i 'error'
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5547]: some error #1
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5549]: some error #2
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5551]: some error #3
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5553]: some error #4
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5555]: some error #5
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5557]: some error #6
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5559]: some error #7
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5561]: some error #8
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5563]: some error #9
Feb 20 13:50:10 localhost [5565]: some error #10
```

it works, but when i try to use it in **infinity while loop** to listen in "live mode", it not works:

```
journalctl -f -n 0 | grep -i 'error' | while read line; do echo "Error detected"; done
```

How i can do that? Thanks!

Comment: while read line; do echo "Error detected"; done  - this is my infinity while loop, when i tail journald and find error, while loop must do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `while` loop doesn't get any input until the output buffer of `grep` is full.

The most portable workaround is to replace your `grep` with a `case` statement:

```bash
journalctl -f -n 0 |
while read line
do
    case $line in
        *[eE][rR][rR][oO][rR]*)
            echo "Error detected"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

**remark:** Depending on your platform, you might be able to use `stdbuf -oL grep -i 'error'` or a bash regex instead of `case`.